# Overuse of emailed 'feedback' surveys

Tags: customer-experience

Being emailed a 'feedback survey' for any transaction where an organisation (on or offline) has your email address is becoming very common.

(and if you don't complete it you get numerous emails reminding you to complete it !)...

How does an organisation get feedback on it's services - without just annoying its customers ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way for an organization to get feedback on it's services - without just annoying its customers are **Customer feedback bots** which transforms the survey experience. What was once an act of filling out a boring form is now a conversation. A conversation you load with your brand personality. And users appreciate this shift!

Leaving feedback through conversation makes it all the more enjoyable which increases the chances that your customers will take the time to provide you with the information you need. Caring about pleasant experience not just before but also during a survey is an extra mile down the differentiation lane.

Bots let you take your customers down different conversation threads based on their answers. Hence, you a chance to react to particular problems there and then.

For instance, if a customer complains about a problem you are aware of, you can have the bot offer them a discount voucher in the middle of the survey.

With a traditional survey, you can see how many people accessed the form and how many people submitted it. However, you have no idea what happened to those who didn’t make it all the way to the end.

Bot analytics are more thorough and let you follow customer behavior throughout the questionnaire. You have the opportunity to identify points of friction and improve your conversion flow.

Comment: + 1 - I like this idea: so you can tell the Bot the one thing you really want to say, without having to wade through pages of surveys looking for a free text field.

Comment: Thanks, its a way to collect feelings, thoughts, and impressions and turn them into actionable data – a much better way than online surveys & questionnaires.

Answer (score 0):

Make it short, easy, relevant and targeted.

Allow people to opt out.