# how to implement in-page surveys efficiently?

Tags: ux-designer, surveys, data-collection

We are planning to release a feature soon named "Duplicate ad Campaign".

Our users are external company employees and till now after releasing any features, we were getting their feedback about the feature and usability issues directly through users hearing.

From now on we're planning to do it systematically somewhat like placing a survey on that page and users who used that feature would be asked to give feedback.

Do you think is it a good approach and if yes, is there any best practice on how to do it efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way for an organization to get feedback on its services - without just annoying its customers are **Customer feedback bots** which transform the survey experience. You can check my yesterdays' reply [Customer feedback bots](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/124783/106852)

Its a way to collect feelings, thoughts, and impressions and turn them into actionable data – a much better way than online surveys & questionnaires

However, if you are determined to place a survey instead, try to keep it as short as possible and make them personalized. Also, try to incentivize the survey participation like offer a 10% discount in exchange for feedback

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.  It makes sense to me.